# GIT-No supported authentication methods available

Tags: git, ssh

I am using git version 2.6.2.windows.1 , I have suddenly started getting below error message while cloning the git repository on git bash :

```
$ git clone URL && scp -p -P 29418 URL:hooks/xxxxx/.git/hooks/
Cloning into 'xxxx'...
FATAL ERROR: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: What version of Git are you using? On which OS? (Same questions on the server side)

Comment: git version 2.6.2 and windows 7 on client side. git version 1.7.1 and RedHat 6.3 on the server side

Comment: Was it working before? What changed?

Comment: yes it was working before. Nothing has changed AFAIK

Comment: you need to check your ssh connection: `ssh -Tv git@yourServer`

Comment: My ssh seems to work fine   ssh -p <29418 user@Url>

  ****    Welcome to Gerrit Code Review    ****

  Hi User, you have successfully connected over SSH.

  Unfortunately, interactive shells are disabled.
  To clone a hosted Git repository, use:

  git clone ssh://user@XXXXX:29418/REPOSITORY_NAME.git

Connection to XXXX closed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123445/discussion-between-sakshi-and-vonc).

Comment: Does the git clone alone work? Is it the scp which fails?

Answer (score -1):

export Git_SSH=/c/Users/user-name/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/bin/ssh.exe made it work.